# What is the equivalent of Kotlin's Flow.mapLastest in Dart Stream?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

In Kotlin there is `Flow.mapLastest()` function that:

> Returns a flow that emits elements from the original flow transformed
> by transform function. When the original flow emits a new value,
> computation of the transform block for previous value is cancelled.

I saw that the package `stream_transform` has some extension methods like `SwitchLastest()` which is the same that `Flow.flatMapLastest()`, but i don't know how i can implement the Flow.mapLastest().

Is there an equivalent function for Dart's Stream?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Dart, but from a quick browse in `stream_transform`, it seems like [`asyncMapSample`](https://pub.dev/documentation/stream_transform/latest/stream_transform/AsyncMap/asyncMapSample.html) is pretty close to what you want?

Comment: @Sweeper thanks for replying, I saw the `asyncMapSample` and it doesn't work because that method discard all events from the source while the `converter` is executing, that means that the last events are discarded. `mapLastest` method, cancel the current event transform operarion if a new event is generated from the source and starts the `converter` process in this last event.